# MarkLogic Search Xquery

Tags: marklogic

Using following 2 MarkLogic Xqueries inorder to get expected result:

1. To list out all documents by timestamp

   ```
   for $x in xdmp:document-properties()//prop:last-modified  
   order by $x descending 
   return <uri>{xdmp:node-uri($x)} {$x}</uri>
   ```
2. To search string in the document from the lastest file

   ```
   for $a in doc("/contentC:/MLDemo/DataFiles/1234.xml")/*//@System_Name
   where $a ="Exchange"
   return $a
   ```

I am new to Marklogic and Xquery. Can someone plesae help me To combine these two individual scripts into one script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question shows little research effort.

Comment: Unclear what expected result should be.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you aren't changing the default configuration, `prop:last-modified` should help.

See https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/properties to learn more about properties.

Note that `/*//@System_Name where $a ="Exchange"` will not perform well for large databases. Specify an element and use an XPath predicate. Try something more like `/a/b/c[@d eq $value]` - or if you have multiple elements `/a/b/(c|d|e)[@z eq $value]`

Answer (score 1):

`let $URI:=<uris>{
  for $x in xdmp:document-properties()//prop:last-modified

  order by $x descending 
  return <uri>{xdmp:base-uri($x)}</uri>
  }</uris>`

`for $a in $URI//uri
let $doc:= doc($a)/*//@System_Name
where $a ="Exchange"
return $a`

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers to this question.

I'd recommend you learn basic XQuery syntax.  For example, try [http://www.amazon.com/XQuery-Priscilla-Walmsley/dp/0596006349](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596006349)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. i would appreciate if you could provide me a solution right away ... thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
for $a in doc("/contentC:/MLDemo/DataFiles/1234.xml")/*//@System_Name
return 
if($a eq "Exchange") then
       for $x in xdmp:document-properties()//prop:last-modified  
       order by $x descending 
       return <uri>{xdmp:node-uri($x)} {$x}</uri>
else ()
```